# Solana Web3.js: Getting `null` for Mint account, althought it should return an `AccountInfo` object

Tags: web3js, solana, solana-web3js

When I run `connection.getAccountInfo(watermelonMint.key);` I get a `null` object, although it should return an `AccountInfoObject`. Any idea why this is the case? When I look for the address associated with this mint on solana explorer, I get normal statistics (https://explorer.solana.com/address/7vLEZP5JHhKVg3HEGSWcFNaxAKg7L633uMT7ePqmn98V?cluster=devnet)

```
console.log("Watermelon mint is: ");
console.log(watermelonMint);
```

returns

```
Mint {conn: Connection, key: PublicKey}
conn: Connection {_commitment: undefined, _confirmTransactionInitialTimeout: undefined, _rpcEndpoint: 'https://api.devnet.solana.com', _rpcWsEndpoint: 'wss://api.devnet.solana.com/', _rpcClient: ClientBrowser, …}
key: PublicKey
_bn: BN {negative: 0, words: Array(11), length: 10, red: null}
[[Prototype]]: Struct
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

any idea what could cause this?

---

Update 1:

basically, `Token.getMintInfo();` keeps failing

```
const token = new Token(conn, mint, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, {} as any)
  console.log("Getting token: ", token);
  let out: Promise<MintInfo> = token.getMintInfo();
  console.log("Out is: ", out);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, `mint` in "Update 1" is incorrect, or that your connection is improperly defined somewhere.  Can you double-check that `mint` is equal to `PublicKey("7vLEZP5JHhKVg3HEGSWcFNaxAKg7L633uMT7ePqmn98V")`?

Also, can you make sure to `await` the response from `token.getMintInfo()`?

Comment: I had mixed up devnet and testnet by having hardcoded strings instead of environment variables. thank you so much!